# Ansible is not creating .retry files

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible 2.8 version and i do not see .retry files getting created if the playbook fails to execute tasks on servers. 
I do not see any error message as such

Entries in ansible.cfg are as below. 
Since the retry_files_enabled defaults to true i have not made any changes to cfg file. Does anyone know the reason why it isnt creating .retry files?

```
#retry_files_enabled = False
#retry_files_save_path = ~/.ansible-retry
```

Comment: I'm using custom hosts file, naming convention similar to 'test-hosts'.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the actual values of configuration by running

```
ansible-config dump
```

The reason the Ansible behavior is different from the value in a configuration file is that Ansible have few possible places to look for configuration files, and some of them may have higher preference than your. (f.e. ansible.cfg in the directory with the playbook).

Comment: Thanks for quick turnaround.  It does say default is false!! 
`RETRY_FILES_ENABLED(default) = False
RETRY_FILES_SAVE_PATH(default) = None`

But i guess in 2.7 version .retry files was default getting created ?!?!

Comment: Maybe they've changed the default. I always disable them (they are useless in big projects). You can enable them, if you want, in your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour was changed via this proposal:

https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/155

`RETRY_FILES_ENABLED` now defaults to False